# How to create Star Schema Benchmark (SSB) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, olap, star-schema

I've tried to create a Star Schema Benchmark (SSB) in SQL Server with its data. I downloaded `HammerDB` and `DBGen.exe` to create it. But these tools are just for creating TPC-H Benchmarks.

I created an SSB schema in SQL Server manually. How can I populate these tables with `DBGen.exe`? And also how to generate OLAP Queries `qgen.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

The [Can not open include file 'vcruntime.h' error.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c21a711-8509-4030-9458-7b2979894baa/can-not-open-include-file-vcruntimeh-error?forum=vcgeneral) link shows how to compile Star Schema Benchmark with Visual C++.